# how to determine when a script has loaded and executed

Tags: javascript

I need to run some code after a script has been loaded **and executed**. The code I have seems to work ok most of the time, but occasionally it will run before the script has actually executed.

In the loaded script I have

```
var script_loaded = true;
```

And I am loading it like so:

```
// Handle Script loading - borrowed from jquery
var done = false;
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (!done
        && (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete")) {
        done = true;
        expect(script_loaded).to.be.true; //chai testing
    }
};
document.head.appechChild(script);
```

This test will fail with *script_loaded* being undefined approximately 10% of the time (testing in Chrome).

Is there anyway to ensure a loaded script has actually run before proceeding, without knowing the contents of said script?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can have list of loaded file in array. And before loading any other script just check the array, if it's there than skip otherwise load it.

Comment: you might setTimeout for 0 in the script load handler and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the suggestion! I actually tried it at 1 to no affect. I was thinking of increasing the time, but that leads down a road of bad practice, so I opted to post here in case there was a way to do this consistently.

Comment: As it turns out, the issue is related to randomness of the load order. Occasionally the scripts would load in a way that would throw things off when the scripts depend on each other. The solution was to wait for each one to load before processing the next. I will update my post to reflect my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution would be in main script or page put:

```
if(!window['zw']) window['zw']={};
zw.scriptLoaded=false;
zw.makeLoaded=function()
{
    this.scriptLoaded=true;
    alert('script has been loaded!');
}
```

Then at then end of your loadinng script:

```
if(!window['zw']) window['zw']={};
if(zw.makeLoaded) zw.makeLoaded();
```

I think it will work for you. If there are several files to load you could create a class to handle loads. It's another approach but it works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any control over the files being loaded. Is there a way to do this without any knowledge of what's in the loaded script?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. This had to do with the randomness of the load order, and certain scripts depending on that load order. Processing each one at a time seems to have fixed the issue.

Here is my code if anyone cares to use it...

**edit**

I updated the code to better demonstrate the concept

```
   function loadScriptList(list, callback) {
    var queue = [];

    var process = function() {
        if (queue.length === 0) {
            callback();
            return;
        }

        //remove next loader from queue and call it
        queue.shift().apply();
    };

    //returns a loader function that can be processed in a queue
    var createLoader = function(src) {
        return function() {
            console.log("Loading " + src)
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', src);
            // Handle Script loading - borrowed from jquery
            var isLoaded = false;
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                //process the next item in the queue when ready
                if (!isLoaded
                    && (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete")) {
                    console.log("Done.");
                    isLoaded = true;
                    process();
                }
            };
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        };
    };

    //build a queue of load functions, then process it
    list.forEach(function(src) {
        queue.push(createLoader(src));
    });
    process();
}

function loadComplete() {
    alert("Load Complete");
}

loadScriptList(['script_01.js', 'script_02.js', 'script_03.js'], 
               loadComplete);
```